# Adding figure to JRadioButtonMenuItem

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon, jradiobutton

I have to create a simple Text Editor which has menu bar with specific options.

One of them is to change font colors by selecting it on `JRadioButtonMenuItem` which has to look exactly as professor described in the picture.

My problem is that I don't know how to create and add those little circles between text and radio button.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You could use some special unicode symbol, like U+26AB, that is ⚫

Comment: While you might also use a circular colored icon as shown in [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JRadioButtonMenuItem.html#<init>(java.lang.String,javax.swing.Icon)), I'd first try the method suggested by @Rocco.

Comment: @Rocco my professor clarified that we need to create those circles on our own in the new Class that implements Icon interface. And that is where my problem begins 'cause I haven't used this interface and never made any figure like that in the past. Then I need to, somehow, add this circle to the Radio Buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I've managed to solve my problem by using Icon interface. Here's a little part of my code with final result. I'm still open for any kind of tips and improvements to my code to make it better and learn by coding properly.

Here's my Circle class:

```
public class Circle implements Icon {
    Color color;

    public Circle(Color color){
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawOval(x, y, getIconWidth(), getIconHeight());
        g.fillOval(x, y, getIconWidth(), getIconHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconWidth() {
        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconHeight() {
        return 7;
    }
}
```

and my GUI method of showing menu bar:

```
private void myMenuBar(
        ...
        JMenu optionsForeground,
        JRadioButtonMenuItem optionsForeBlue
) {

    ...
    optionsForegroundBlue.setForeground(color);
    optionsForegroundBlue.setIcon(new Circle(color));

    optionsForeground.add(optionsForeBlue);
    options.add(optionsForeground);

    options.add(optionsBackground);
    options.add(optionsFontSize);

    menuBar.add(file);
    menuBar.add(edit);
    menuBar.add(options);
}
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJRE7.png)